# Perl formatting to display 2 loops separately

Tags: perl, format

I am having the below hash of hash,

```
my $hash = {1 => {'a'=>'a1','b'=>'b1', 'c'=>'c1', 'd'=>'d1'},
    2 => {'a'=>'e1','b'=>'f1', 'c'=>'g1', 'd'=>'h1'},
    3 => {'a'=>'i1','b'=>'j1','c'=>'k1', 'd'=>'l1'},
    4 => {'a'=>'m1','b'=>'n1','c'=>'o1','d'=>'p1'}};
```

I want to display the above hash of hash in perl formatted manner. The hash of hash is dynamic in nature so we can have additional keys later on as well.

I am using the below code to generate the hash of hash into a proper format.

```
use strict;
my $hash = {1 => {'a'=>'a1','b'=>'b1', 'c'=>'c1', 'd'=>'d1'},
        2 => {'a'=>'e1','b'=>'f1', 'c'=>'g1', 'd'=>'h1'},
        3 => {'a'=>'i1','b'=>'j1','c'=>'k1', 'd'=>'l1'},
        4 => {'a'=>'m1','b'=>'n1','c'=>'o1','d'=>'p1'}};

my @a = qw(1 2);
my @b = qw(3 4);
&displayreport($hash, \@a);
print "new display\n\n";
&displayreport($hash, \@b);
my($i,$j,$k,$l); 
format STDOUT_TOP =
 A  B   C   D
 -- --  --  --
.
format OUTPUT=
@<< @<< @<< @<<
$i,$j,$k,$l
.

sub displayreport{
    my ($x, $y) = @_;

    $~ = "STDOUT_TOP";
    write;
    foreach(@$y) {
        $i = $hash->{$_}->{a};
        $j = $hash->{$_}->{b};
        $k = $hash->{$_}->{c};
        $l = $hash->{$_}->{d};
        $~ = "OUTPUT";
        write();
    }
}
```

The Output I got is,

```
 A      B       C       D
 --     --      --      --
 A      B       C       D
 --     --      --      --
a1      b1      c1      d1
e1      f1      g1      h1

new display

 A      B       C       D
 --     --      --      --
i1      j1      k1      l1
m1      n1      o1      p1
```

where the header in the first case is repeated.

I need the output as,

```
 A      B       C       D
 --     --      --      --
a1      b1      c1      d1
e1      f1      g1      h1

new display

 A      B       C       D
 --     --      --      --
i1      j1      k1      l1
m1      n1      o1      p1
```

Where I am doing wrong. Kindly assist.

Comment: `_TOP` named formats are special => http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html#Top-of-Form-Processing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename `STDOUT_TOP` to `STDOUT_TOPX` and it works. But I have no idea why.

Answer (score 1):

[`format`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/format.html)'s suffixed with `_TOP` have special meaning as [Top of Form Processing](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html#Top-of-Form-Processing)

You can take advantage of this more explicitly by opening an output to a new filehandle, and using the `$^` variable for setting a `$FORMAT_TOP_NAME`.

This is demonstrated by the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash = {
    1 => { 'a' => 'a1', 'b' => 'b1', 'c' => 'c1', 'd' => 'd1' },
    2 => { 'a' => 'e1', 'b' => 'f1', 'c' => 'g1', 'd' => 'h1' },
    3 => { 'a' => 'i1', 'b' => 'j1', 'c' => 'k1', 'd' => 'l1' },
    4 => { 'a' => 'm1', 'b' => 'n1', 'c' => 'o1', 'd' => 'p1' },
};

displayreport( $hash, [1,2] );

print "\nnew display\n";
displayreport( $hash, [3,4] );

format OUTPUT_TOP =
 A   B   C   D
 --  --  --  --
.

my ( $i, $j, $k, $l );
format OUTPUT=
 @<< @<< @<< @<<
$i,$j,$k,$l
.

sub displayreport {
    my ( $hash, $keys ) = @_;

    open my $fh, '>', \my $output or die "Can't open: $!";
    my $ofh = select($fh);

    $^ = "OUTPUT_TOP";
    $~ = "OUTPUT";

    foreach (@$keys) {
        ($i, $j, $k, $l) = @{$hash->{$_}}{qw(a b c d)};
        write();
    }

    select($ofh);
    close $fh;
    print $output;
}
```

Outputs:

```
 A   B   C   D
 --  --  --  --
 a1  b1  c1  d1
 e1  f1  g1  h1

new display
 A   B   C   D
 --  --  --  --
 i1  j1  k1  l1
 m1  n1  o1  p1
```

#### Two Alternatives

First, if you really want to use formats, I suggest you use the more modern [`Perl6::Form`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form).

Second, I would strongly recommend using the much simpler [`printf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/printf.html) and [`sprintf`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/sprintf.html) for this type of basic formatting and skip formats all together:

```
displayreport( $hash, [1,2] );

print "\nnew display\n";
displayreport( $hash, [3,4] );

sub displayreport {
    my ( $hash, $keys ) = @_;

    my $fmt = " %3s %3s %3s %3s\n";

    printf $fmt, qw(A B C D);
    printf $fmt, qw(-- -- -- --);

    foreach (@$keys) {
        printf $fmt, @{$hash->{$_}}{qw(a b c d)};
    }
}
```

Output is identical to the previous script.